# Is there a way to restart running instances of Firebase Functions (GCloud Functions) without redeploying?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

In production, I'd like to be able to allow a Firebase / GCloud administrator to restart Firebase Function (GCloud Function) instances without having to perform a redeployment.

Use cases include reloading in memory cached values from an external service or when performing key rotation in the Secret Manager.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 3):

Having a general solution to restart functions is the most useful in production as sometimes a rare state condition can be quickly reset by an admin without resorting to a redeployment (which they might not be able to do).

In researching a caching & secret management solution, I found these potential solutions:

**Option 1.** Use a Firestore database trigger to reload the cached objects but I don't think this event will fire in all running instances (just one!) so probably not a viable or safe solution.

**Option 2.** Poll the database on every function invocation to checking if a database value has changed to trigger cache reload. You'd have to do this on every function invocation so it kinda defeats the purpose of having a cache to improve performance and lower costs.

**Option 3.** Use a timer to periodically clear the cache. Has the downside of having to wait for this to happen and can mean that running instances may have different cached values at the same time (unless you're careful about setting the timer). Not really a good solution for key rotation use cases where you often need to force a reload immediately after setting the new key on another external service.

**Option 4.** Change an environment variable and detect this change to trigger clearing/reloading the cache or secret. Environment variables are propagated to all running instances. *I currently think this is probably the best and simplest way*. Could also be combined with the timer method. NOTE: I've not yet **proven** that changing an environment variable will change it for new requests in existing running instances.

**Option 5** Can use the [Cloud Runtime Configuration API](https://cloud.google.com/deployment-manager/runtime-configurator/reference/rest/) and [watch for changes](https://cloud.google.com/deployment-manager/runtime-configurator/reference/rest/v1beta1/projects.configs.variables/watch) to configuration variables.

**Option 6** For secrets you can [mount a secret as a volume](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/configuring/secrets#mounting_the_secret_as_a_volume). This is a good strategy if you want to reference the latest version of the secret. For example, if the secret has been mounted to /etc/secrets/secret1, then the function has to read this file like so:

```
fs.readFileSync('/etc/secrets/secret1')
```

Follow [these instructions](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/configuring/secrets#making_a_secret_accessible_to_a_function) to configure a secret to be accessible as a mounted file. There are also details here for manually setting up secrets as environment variables but for Firebase functions there better is a [supported method](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/config-env#secret_parameters) that is done via code.

**Unknowns**

- When a secret is configured to become an environment variable for a function, it's possible that the GCloud/Firebase Functions runtime will already propagate this change to all instances via the environment variable being updated. Yet to be tested.

**Feature Wish List**

- Allow a restart of one or all functions via Firebase or GCloud Console
- Provide a API to restart function instances so it can be done programmatically. This is important for some system admin tools.
- Firebase Functions that register secrets will subscribe to changes in the Secret Manager and restart when secrets are updated.
- Register a Firebase event trigger to run in all active instances